# Problems with allocating memory for a matrix in c

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, memset

I'm trying to allocate memory to a matrix in a function and then print its values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void cria_ilhas(int** ilhas, int n){
    int i, p;
    ilhas = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        ilhas[i] = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for (p=0; p<n; p++)
            ilhas[i][p] = 4;
    }
    printf("value %d\n",ilhas[0][0]);
}

void main(){
    int n=5, i, j;
    int **ilhas;
    cria_ilhas(ilhas, n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",ilhas[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

But this is the output:

```
value 4
Segmentation fault
```

Why i'm having segmentation fault?

How can I use memset in this kind of matrix?

Comment: That is not a matrix, but an array of pointer to (array of) int. Note that you should not cast the result of `malloc` & friends. C is not C++!

Comment: The `ilhas` in the function is not the same as the `ilhas` in `main`. Put a `printf("%p\n",ilhas)` at the end of the function, and before/after the function call in `main`.

Comment: Well, i think that basically all matrix are an array of pointers to arrays of value types.

Comment: No, a matrix is normally a 2-dimensional array of equal types. You are having two different types, which happen to use the same syntax as a 2D array to access the elements of the second dimension. This due to C overloading the index-operator for pointers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re doing it almost correctly. When you’re calling `cria_ilhas`, you’re passing in the variable `ilhas`, and expecting that when you change it inside of the function, that effects the variable in `main`, too. Unfortunately, C doesn’t work that way.<sup>1</sup>

What you’ll want to do is remove the `ilhas` parameter from `cria_ilhas` and stop passing it in when you call it in `main`. Then just declare `ilhas` as a local variable in `cria_ilhas`. To get the value back to main, you’ll need to return it from `cria_ilhas`, and in `main`, when you call it, assign `ilhas` to its result.

<sup>1</sup> Side note: if you were using C++, you could make it work by changing the parameter from `int **ilhas` to `int **&ilhas`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this shape and tell me if it worked

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int** cria_ilhas( int n){
    int i, p;
    int **ilhas
    ilhas = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            ilhas[i] = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
            for (p=0; p<n; p++)
                ilhas[i][p] = 4;
         }
    printf("value %d\n",ilhas[0][0]);
    return ilhas;
}
void main(){
    int n=5, i, j;
    int **ilhas;
    ilhas = cria_ilhas(n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",ilhas[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
}
```

I think it should work for you, your code is much likely to be true but the problem is you have defined a large structure in heap (ilhas definition in main method) and you sent it address to a method ( call by reference) which suppose to allocate memory for it from stack segment but not heap, if you pass the address of a simple type variable to a method, it woundnt be a problem but allocating memory for array's will raise segmentation problem.

Comment: Looks like I am not lucky today!

Comment: So when I do `ilhas = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));` I am changing the pointer in function but not returning it to `main`, right?
So if I allocatte the array of pointers in `main` and then modifying the content in function, it will work?

Comment: In above code , I have defined two ilhas one inside the method and the other is the one in the main method which you had before, I am just trying to define and allocate the ilhas variable in a single method, if you do this in cria_ilhas it will be defined in stack segment, but if you defin it in main it will go to heap from code segment,I wrote what icktoofay is saying, we both mentioned same  solution. good luck with that